# How do I make my custom map annotations' titles always visible in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I am trying to display a number of annotations on an `MKMapView`. In my initial setup, using Apple's default pin markers, the title of each annotation was always visible on the map, when tapped the subtitle would appear. But since I created custom markers to replace the default ones, the titles are not visible unless I tap the annotation, at which point the title appears along with the subtitle.

I want to restore the previous behaviour, and was wondering is there a way of setting the titles to always appear? I am working in Objective-C. Apple documentation points to this function in Swift:

```
var titleVisibility: MKFeatureVisibility { get set }
```

How would I go about doing this in Objective-C? I currently have set the following parameters:

```
 annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
 annotationView.enabled = YES;
 annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
```

, so I'm looking for something along the lines of:

annotationView."some parameter to select the title visibility" = "YES/ON/VISIBLE,, or whatever the expression may be";

thanks in advance if anybody is able to help

Comment: try this code [mapView selectAnnotation:annotationView animated:NO];

Answer (score 0):

`titleVisibility` is `MKMarkerAnnotationView`'s property. Replace `MKAnnotationView` with `MKMarkerAnnotationView`.

e.g.

```
MKMarkerAnnotationView *pin = (MKMarkerAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

if (!pin) {

    pin = [[MKMarkerAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    pin.titleVisibility = MKFeatureVisibilityVisible;
    pin.subtitleVisibility = MKFeatureVisibilityVisible;
    pin.displayPriority = MKFeatureDisplayPriorityRequired;
    pin.animatesWhenAdded = YES;
    pin.canShowCallout = YES;
    pin.draggable = NO;
} else {
    pin.annotation = annotation;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but what happened was the default Apple pins came back, along with the ones i had created (each was pushing the other off the actual coordinate) With pin.titleVisibility = MKFeatureVisibilityVisible; the title was visible, but also the subtitle. So i set annotationView.titleVisibility = MKFeatureVisibilityVisible;
                annotationView.subtitleVisibility = MKFeatureVisibilityHidden; but this did nothing. As I understand it from my reading, MKMarkerAnnotationView is a way of displaying the default pins, and MKAnnotationView is what's required for custom markers.

Comment: So I need a way of implementing MKMarkerAnnotationView and an ability to disable the default pins, or i need to implement MKAnnotationView with an ability to display the titles permanently. I also need a way to display the title without the subtitle unless clicked, rather than none or both.

Comment: @Tim Did you solve the problem? I have the same one.